# Wordpress count_posts() equivalent function non-expensive method

Tags: php, wordpress, function, count

I'm looking to count the number of posts in the last week then group them by a custom taxonomy called 'topic' So that in the next get_posts equation I can get topics by the number of posts to that area in the last week.

It can be done like this with get posts, but I am concerned that this is unnecessarily expensive on the server. Is there another way?

```
function count_posts_by_taxanomy($since,$taxonomy){
    global $sincer;
    $sincer = $since;

    function filter_post_count($where = ''){
        global $sincer;
        $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime($sincer)) . "'";
        return $where;
    }

    $args = array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'suppress_filters' => false
    );

    add_filter('posts_where','filter_post_count');
    $posts = get_posts($args);
    remove_filter('posts_where','filter_post_count');

    $count_term = array();

    foreach($posts as $post){
        foreach(get_the_terms($post->ID,'topic') as $term){
            $count_term[$term->slug] += 1;
        }
    }
    print_r($count_term);

}
```

Called like this:

```
count_posts_by_taxanomy('-5 days','topic');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be better using a custom database query. See here for more info on that: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

I would then suggest you store the result in a transient. You don't need to run the query on every load.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API

Comment: I like the Transient bit, presumably it could be combined with a CRON JOB to perform an update each hour or so?

Comment: You'd set the transient to expire after 1h so a CRON job wouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WP_Query and call $wp_query->found_posts to find count of posts. And then do a loop and cache values.

More at : http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

```
$query = new WP_Query( array('posts_per_page'=>-1,
'post_type'=>array('post'),
'date_query' => array(array('after' => 'YOUR DATE')),   
'tax_query' => array(
array(
'taxonomy' => 'YOUR TAX'
))));
```